# ffmpeg copying audio and reencoding video causes encode error in Iphone player

Tags: ffmpeg, iphone

ffmpeg -i a.ts -y -s 352x480 -r 16 -c:v libx264 -b 32k  -g 30 -vprofile baseline -level 30 -refs 1  -qp 36 -preset ultrafast  -c:a copy  o.ts is not played by Iphone player. It says decoding error or something like that.

but ffmpeg -i a.ts -y -s 352x480 -r 16 -c:v libx264 -b 32k  -g 30 -vprofile baseline -level 30 -refs 1  -qp 36 -preset ultrafast  -strict experimental -c:a aac  o.ts is played....

ts is inside m3u8...

Any idea why?
The input audio is aac.
I have this theory. The framerate is set to 16, frames will disappear. So it will not be synchronised with the audio any longer. The question how does a video player match the given video with corresponding audio track?  I guess it must be using some kind of timestamp...
Could the timestamps be so different that the player does not find the audio for the given video frame?  How could I check that? would ffmpeg use the same starting timestap for the video automatically?

Comment: What device are you using, exactly? Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output for each `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: anybody else, I added extra thought, can you guess what can be wrong?